# Progress status of file upload in smtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, smtpclient

How can i implement a progress bar for uploading a file via `smtp` client.

I want to see the advance detail for e.g. Number of bytes sent out of? I am developing a **windows form application** of simple email client. I'm looking for code sample. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show your relevant, current code.

Comment: It's not possible to check the progress using SmtpClient, since it doesn't provide a ProgressChanged or similar event. You can just subscribe to SendCompleted event, to know when has it finished.